# Qual é a utilidade dos operadores bitwise de deslocamento?

Tags: operadores, bitwise

Recentemente eu descobri os operadores bitwise de deslocamento `<<` e `>>`. Eu sei que esses operadores deslocam os bits para a esquerda e direita, mas qual a utilidade de fazer isso ?

Em quais casos esses operadores de deslocamento são usados ?